# Doctrine dbal стоит ли использовать

Tags: php, mysqli, doctrine2, doctrine

Можете дать небольшой совет по использованию Doctrine dbal, стоит ли его вообще использовать?

Недавно делал тесты по скорости выполнения запросов
MYSQLi(Standart) и Doctrine dbal(MYSQLi Driver). Тесты немного удивили меня.

**Это на локальном**

- Doctrine dbal → 100 000 выполнил за 73.257080078125
- MYSQLi(Standart) → 100 000 выполнил за 22.825722932816

**На сервере**

- Doctrine dbal → 100 000 запросов выполнил за 65.95
- MYSQLi(Standart) → 100 000 запросов выполнил за 19.32

---

- Doctrine dbal → 10 000 запросов выполнил за 7.8542101383209
- MYSQLi(Standart) → 10 000 запросов выполнил за 2.6818990707397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doctrine dbal стоит ли использовать

При решении об использовании того или иного драйвера, количество запросов врядли будет браться в расчёт. Время выполнения запроса явно в адекватном бекенде будет зависеть не от драйвера а от заполненности СУБД, типа СУБД, и сложности запросов. Насколько изящно делаются запросы - вот что главное, насколько безопасно и просто программисту работать с ними. Поэтому отвечу на вопрос:

Конечно стоит.  mysqli слишком не ООП-шный, оставляет возможность трешкодить и делать дыры в безопасности.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine dbal - Я читал его документацию, вроде там все отлично они сделали, просто меня удивило время выполнения запросов, из-за этого.